# Html form is not working on Facebook fan page with "Static Html Iframe Tabs"

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I've a html form in my facebook fan page which i integrate with "Static Html Iframe Tabs." This form is process by php. In html "action attribute" I set this :

```
<form method="post" action="http://formulairefb.gastronoome.com/facebookapp/process.php"  
onSubmit="return validateForm();" name="recipe" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

After submit the form, It's successfully return the form value in my server/website "process.php" page only by using "Opera Browser" But It's not working on "Firefox" or "Chrome Browser".

My questions :
1)  Why it's not sending form value using "Firefox" or "Chrome Browser" ?
2) Is there any other solution for that which perfectly work ?

What I need using this form:
I need to get form value and then insert these form value to my website database.

Thanks and your help is very much welcome.

Comment: Most likely because your app in FB is loaded via HTTPS (now the case for all users), but you are trying to submit the data to an insecure HTTP address.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your reply. Well, I've not https certificate so Is there any other solutions for that ?

Comment: No, you will have to get one. All apps integrated into facebook.com require SSL.

Comment: HTTPS is required, but there's also CORS problem, send your data as json, are you sure that your `process.php` from another domain?